# Azure Devops Pipeline cross product of multiple matrix options

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

The Azure DevOps pipeline documentation provides an example of using `matrix` to build two different OS and version combinations:

```
strategy:
  matrix:
    jdk10_linux:
      imageName: "ubuntu-latest"
      jdkVersion: "1.10"
    jdk11_windows:
      imageName: "windows-latest"
      jdkVersion: "1.11"
```

see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/customize-pipeline?view=azure-devops)

Question: Is there a way to get a cross-product of multiple sets of matrix options.  Suppose for example, I want this:

```
strategy:
  matrix:
    jdk10_linux:
      imageName: "ubuntu-latest"
      jdkVersion: "1.10"
    jdk11_linux:
      imageName: "ubuntu-latest"
      jdkVersion: "1.11"
    jdk10_windows:
      imageName: "windows-latest"
      jdkVersion: "1.10"
    jdk11_windows:
      imageName: "windows-latest"
      jdkVersion: "1.11"
```

Is there a cleaner/easier way to do this besides copy and paste the entire list?

Logically, I'd like to be able to say something more like:

```
imageList: ['windows-latest', 'ubuntu-latest']
jdkList: ['1.10', '1.11']
optionList: ['a','b','c']

strategy:
  matrix_combine_lists:
    imageName: imageList
    jdkVersion: jdkList
    someOption: optionList
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if it is possible using matrix but matrix is just about running jobs in parallel with a different set of parameters so using [Each Template Expression](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/each-expression.md) should work as well:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: imageList
  type: object
  default: ['windows-latest', 'ubuntu-latest']
- name: jdkList
  type: object
  default: ['1.10', '1.11']
- name: optionList
  type: object
  default: ['a','b','c']

jobs:
- ${{ each image in parameters.imageList }}:
  - ${{ each jdk in parameters.jdkList }}:
    - ${{ each option in parameters.optionList }}:
      - job: ${{ replace(image, '-', '_') }}_${{ replace(jdk, '.', '_') }}_${{ option }}
        pool:
          vmImage: ${{ image }}
        steps:
        - script: |
            echo "Image: ${{ image }}, jdk: ${{ jdk }}, option: ${{ option }}"
```

[image]